# Datatable filter remove

Tags: c#, datatable

This filters the datatable correctly:

```
DataView dv2 = dT.DefaultView;
dv2.RowFilter = "myfiled = " + "1";
dT = dv2.ToTable();
```

after this:

```
dT.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
```

The datatable appears empty, I do not understand why.

Comment: Comment out the `dT = dv2.ToTable();` line.

Comment: Is this solved?

Comment: If the line comment no longer function the filter.

Comment: How and where are you using dT?  Your code works for me, otherwise, when I use dT as a DataSource on a DataGridView.

Comment: I have a datatable with the filter in a for loop (aRecord is a Arraylist)
            for (int nRec = 0; nRec < aRecord.Count; nRec++)
            {
                string cNrec = myArraylist[nRec].ToString().Trim();

                dT.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
                DataView dv2 = dT.DefaultView;
                dv2.RowFilter = "rec = " + cNrec;


                dv2.Dispose();

            }

Comment: Sorry the bad format of the text

Comment: Which is why you should put that code from your comment into your question.  Use the edit link for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solving. Declare DefaultView and dispose her out of for loop and work fine.

Comment: Yes, you should _dispose her out_. Works everytime :D

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use null:

```
dT.DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
```